# Event not working with jQuery and Chrome select option

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have the following html code

```
<select>
  <option class="language" langv="en" value="en">English</option>
  <option class="language" langv="fr" value="fr">French</option>
</select>
```

and jquery code,

```
$(".language").click(function(){
  var lang = $(this).attr("langv");

  switch(lang){
      case "en":
         window.location.href = "index.php";
      break;
      case "fr":
         window.location.href = "fr/";
      break;
      default:
         // code
      break;
   }

});
```

The above works perfectly in Firefox and IE but not in Chrome.

Can you please help me out? I am using jquery-1.10.2.

Comment: ya, you cannot bind click event on option element in chrome. So why not using the onchange event of SELECT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `change` event not the `click`

So, my advice is the following.

Change your HTML to:

```
<select class="language">
   <option langv="en" value="en">English</option>
   <option langv="fr" value="fr">French</option>
</select>
```

and change your jQuery to:

```
$(".language").change(function(){
    var lang = $(this).val();
    switch(lang){
       case "en":
         window.location.href = "index.php";
       break;
       case "fr":
         window.location.href = "fr/";
       break;
       default:
         // code
       break;
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a8CX6/)**

If you're using custom attributes I suggest to use  HTML 5 `data-*` attributes. You can take a look at a John Resig's article about them [**over here**](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `.change()` function?

```
$( "select" ).change(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

[jQuery reference](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use onchange event for whole select rather than onclick for its options.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind to onChange event for a dropdownlist:

```
$("select").bind('change',function() {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try binding a change event on the `select` itself. The only thing you have to change in your code is the var `lang`.

```
$("select").change(function(){
    var lang = $(this).find(':selected').attr("langv");

  switch(lang){
      case "en":
         window.location.href = "index.php";
      break;
      case "fr":
         window.location.href = "fr/";
      break;
      default:
         // code
      break;
   }

});
```

Or, since the value is the same as the attribute, you can use this:

```
var lang = $(this).val();
```